# Actions on Google Nodejs getDeviceLocation

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm working on learning Dialogflow with Google Actions and I'm a bit lost with thew new v2 actions-on-google.

I'm attempting to get a device location, however the method I thought was correct is returning undefined.

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I haven't been able to find it.

The code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase- functions');
const { dialogflow, Permission } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('create_log', conv => {
  conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'To locate you',
    permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'
  }));
});

app.intent('user_info', (conv, params, granted) => {
  if (granted) {
    const coordinates = app.getDeviceLocation().coordinates;
    if (coordinates) {            
        conv.close(`You are at ${coordinates}`);
    } else {
        // Note: Currently, precise locaton only returns lat/lng coordinates on phones and lat/lng coordinates 
        // and a geocoded coordinates on voice-activated speakers. 
        // Coarse location only works on voice-activated speakers.`enter code here`
        conv.close('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.');
    }
  } else {
    conv.close('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'd want any method on `app`, even if that one existed, since `app` is available for all Intent Handler calls. Information specific to that conversation is in the `conv` parameter passed to the Intent Handler.

You probably want something more like

```
const coordinates = conv.device.location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, I must have misunderstood what I was reading in the documentation, this works perfect.

Comment: Great! If it has helped you, accepting and/or upvoting the answer is always appreciated.